# How to map a hydraulic circuit efficiently?

Tags: python, network-analysis

I've just started a project for myself, where the goal is to make Python-3 package for modelling hydraulic circuits. So far the results have been promising, but I've met a problem that seem a bit more challenging: How to map out all parallel pathways in a network of unknown complexity, and doing so efficiently? I am sure this is a known problem in network analysis, with advanced third-party solutions available, but I am looking for a less complex solution, as I am not that experienced as a programmer.

So, in the package there are two modules so far: components and system. In the system-module I am working with a Circuit class and a Crawler class, which the latter should have methods for analysing a Circuit object.

The Circuit class has methods for building a list of instances of component objects from given data, and for linking the objects by manipulating a connections attribute. Every component in a Circuit.comp_list thus has pointers "in" and "out" of itself. Nodes will have two or more pointers "in" and/or "out" of itself where the circuit branches or reunites. The pointers are short names (string values) that provide a link to other named components in the circuit, ex: Node.connections attribute with two pointers "out" to named Pipe objects:

```
Node.connections = {"in": {"0": "R#1"}, "out": {"0": "R#2", "1": "R#3"}}
```

So far I've thought of crawling at random through the circuit and adding new leves to a dictionary when branches are found. But I am not sure excatly how to solve this programaticly. I think it should be possible to start with one random component, and follow the links while building the map of routes and parallel pathways. This map would later be used for computing total resistance in the circuit, when matching the circuit with a pump. I'll provide more code on request.

Comment: you can read about different algorithms of graph traversal, this is a general computer science problem with well documented solutions

Comment: Thanks @m.wasowski, the term graph traversal fits the problem I am looking to solve. I am sure I'll find a solution by exploring this term.

Comment: I found some inspiration at [ActiveState Code Receipes](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576723-dfs-and-bfs-graph-traversal/). I were looking for something minimal and less complex as this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [bond graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bond_graph). (These can represent a whole range of dynamic systems. Not just hydraulics but also electrical and mechanical because the governing equations are similar.)

There is a [thesis](https://uwspace.uwaterloo.ca/bitstream/handle/10012/2739/thesis.pdf?sequence=1) from 2006 about simulation sith bond graphs.

You can use the bond graph to derive the system of algebraic and differential equations that govern the system.

If you look around on the internet there are several tools for simulating (partial) differential equations.

Comment: I comment as I start to look into this again. I guess I didn't feel ready to take on the challenge :) Bond graphs certainly seem to lead me in the right direction. Seems interesting as a general tool to model energy exchange networks. The body of knowledge is not easy to grasp, but it's applications are many.